# Unable to download file using anchor link

Tags: javascript, html, web

Unable to download file using anchor link

`

```
<a href={`${url}`} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                hi
              </a>
```

Unable to download file using anchor link its opening instead of downloading.

Comment: Are you looking for the `download` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

In order to download a file, you've to pass `Download` attribute
for example:

```
<a href={`${url}`} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" download>
            hi
          </a>
```